# Slackware 14.2 - /etc/crontab does not exist

Tags: cron, slackware, slackbuilds

When I go to `/var/log/packages/` , I can see there that I have already installed `dcron-4.5-x86_64-5`, which I believe is the same as `crond`.
Now, I want to ensure that permissions on `/etc/crontab` are configured(based on my CIS Benchmark manual), but when I run the command below:

```
stat /etc/crontab
```

It says:

```
stat: cannot stat '/etc/crontab' : No such file or directory.
```

Where will I find that `crontab` file? And am I doing right? What slackware package utilizes crond daemon?

Answer (score 5):

[Dillon's Lightweight Cron Daemon](http://www.jimpryor.net/linux/dcron.html), `dcron`, does not utilize a file named `/etc/crontab`; but, the same functionality is accomplished via the root user's personal crontab file, `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`. By default, the root user's crontab defines the execution of jobs located in the following directories.

- `/etc/cron.hourly`
- `/etc/cron.daily`
- `/etc/cron.weekly`
- `/etc/cron.monthly`

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks. So what package utilizes crond daemon? I could not find it.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a number of cron programs.  That package is Matthew Dillon's, now continued by Jim Pryor.

Dillon cron does not use `/etc/crontab`.  Rather, system-wide jobs go in `/etc/cron.d/`, usually as one file per package.

Dillon cron is not alone in this.

- Thibault Godouet's fcron does not use `/etc/crontab`, either, nor indeed even`/etc/cron.d/`.  For it, you look at files such as `/etc/fcron.allow` and `/etc/fcron.deny`.
- Bruce Guenter's bcron can use `/etc/cron.d/` and `/etc/crontab`, and needs them checking.
- Uwe Ohse's uschedule simply does not use this style of table at all, and its security model is quite different, involving local per-user schedulers.
- Dwayne Bent's systemd-cron does not itself use this style of table either and to ensure that its configuration files are secure you have to look at internal systemd directories.  It imports `/etc/crontab` and files in `/etc/cron.d/` into its native mechanism via a systemd unit generator.
- GNU mcron needs `/var/cron/tabs` and `/etc/crontab` to be checked, although it strongly discourages the use of the latter.

Your manual is assuming one particular piece of software working in one particular way.

## Further reading

- Jim Pryor. *[dcron — dillon's lightweight cron daemon](http://www.jimpryor.net/linux/dcron.html)*.  jimpryor.net.

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks. So what package utilizes crond daemon? I could not find it.